# Как не выводить определённый параметр из базы через R::findAll?

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp

Вывожу с базу данных данные параметры, как можно не выводить параметр test_2?

Код для вывода из базы:

```
$test = 'test.111';
R::findAll('test', "test_1 = $test ORDER BY `id` DESC");
```

Вывод:

```
[
  {
    "id": "5",
    "test_1": "test.111",
    "test_2": "testing.5"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "test_1": "test.111",
    "test_2": "testing.4"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "test_1": "test.111",
    "test_2": "testing.1"
  }
]
```

Comment: `AND field != value`

Comment: @u_mulder как я понимаю вопрос про список полей, а не про критерии отбора?

Comment: Ммм, может и так да.

Comment: @u_mulder , Мне нужно вывести вот так: 

[{"id":"5","test_1":"test.111"},{"id":"4","test_1":"test.111"},{"id":"1","test_1":"test.111"}]

Answer (score 1):

При SQL запросе, вы можете указать какие поля вам "доставать", *по умолчанию* RedBean формирует такой запрос: `SELECT * FROM ...`, `*` - означает выбрать **все** поля.
Давайте укажем RedBean, какие поля выбрать через кастомный `SQL`:

```
    $test = 'test.111';

    $sql = 'SELECT test.id, test.test_1 FROM test 
          WHERE test_1 = :test1 ORDER BY `id` DESC';

    $rows = R::getAll($sql, [
        'test1' => $test
    ]);  // Биндим параметр :test1, и кидаем в него значение $test

    $beans = R::convertToBeans('test',$rows);  // Преобразовываем в объекты 'Bean'
```

Советую так же прочитать информацию про [подготовленные запросы](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php), она вам поможет разобраться в привязывании параметров и поймете что такое 'sql инъекция' :)